# Why does gradle Project API return String for getParent(), when documentation says it must return Parent type?

Tags: gradle, groovy

I am defining a gradle task in which I want to go to the parent directory of the current project. According to the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html, I should have been able to use getParent() property on my current project. But when I try it, it returns a String (path of the parent directory) though the documentation clearly states the method should return a Project. Why is this happening?

Comment: Do you have a runnable example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most certainly you are calling `getParent()` on a file/directory, or inside a closure that delegates to a `java.io.File`, which indeed returns String with parent folder's path.

Try to call `project.parent` explicitly and see if it helps.

ps. Actual code snippet might help as well.

Comment: Yes, it was indeed the case. Thanks for your help, @gusto.